# How to add custom maps to ushahidi

Tags: php, openstreetmap

I would like to add an OSM-like map source (such as opencyclemap, hikebikemap) to ushahidi.
Since it is not possible to do this via the administration interface, how would I go doing this in code?

Thanks,
Dima

Comment: StackOverflow is a site that helps you with specific issues so you'll have to give a bit more info then you have provided now, more in particular the code you tried already and the errors it produces

Answer (score 1):

If you want to add an additional base layer to Ushahidi you'll need to write a plugin, and use the ushahidi_filter.map_layers_js event too add your map.

Here's an example which adds layers from mapbox https://github.com/rjmackay/Ushahidi-plugin-mapbox.